# Why am I getting 'permission denied' with mdutil on my Mac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, permissions, search, macos-mojave

Whenever I try to perform searches in Finder on my external hard drive I get no results.

I've tried re-indexing the drive with Spotlight by going into preferences and adding then removing the drive from the privacy tab. But this appears to have no effect.

I want to use mdutil to get the indexing status of the drive and possibly change it.

```
mdutil -s /Volumes/dev/<disk1>/
```

But when I do this is my result.

```
-bash: disk1: Permission denied
```

I get the same result when I use the same command with sudo or chmod +x.

I don't know why I wouldn't have permission on this drive. I formatted it myself.

When I Get Info of the drive, under Sharing & Permissions it only says "You have custom access." It doesn't give me any option to change read and write status.

This is what I get when I run diskutil list.

```
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:               Windows_NTFS hephaestus              2.0 TB     disk1s1
```

Does anyone know why this might be or how I could fix it?

Comment: Does Get Info show you an 'Ignore permissions for this volume' checkbox at the bottom? That's your quick fix, if it does.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm afraid it does not...

Comment: hmmm… run `diskutil list` & see at least what format it thinks it is.

Comment: @Tetsujin /dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:               Windows_NTFS hephaestus              2.0 TB     disk1s1

Comment: That's why - macOS can't write to NTFS natively. btw, don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. It's considered 'bad form'.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106589/write-in-ntfs-using-mavericks

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok cool thank you!